# error when running npm run build in prestashop local environment

Tags: node.js, npm, webpack, sass, prestashop

I've been stuck for quite a while. I'm currently starting a local environment for Prestashop and when I go into the _dev folder and run npm run build or npm run watch to watch my changes. I receive the error below. I've done rm -rf node_modules and reinstalled them, I have also tried uninstalling webpack and node-sass and reinstalling but still no luck. can somebody tell me where I am going wrong or what is causing this?

[image: error message]

Comment: Could you provide some code (webpack config, package.json, ...)?

Comment: without the webpack config it's going to be hard to help